# Finding the probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Of the bolt manufactured for a certain application, 90% meet the length specification and can be used immediately, 6% are too long and can be used after being cut, and 4% are too short and must be scrapped.

(1) Find the probability that a randomly selected bolt can be used (either immediately or after being cut).

(2) Find the probability that fewer than 9 out of a sample of 10 bolts can be used.

Comment: Where did you get stuck (epspecially at the first part)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets call a product good if it can be used or if it is too long. 
Let G be the event that a product is good. Let U be the event that a product can be used right away, and let L be the event that a product is too long.

(1)  $P(G) = P(U \cup L) = P(U) + P(L) = 0.96$

Let X be the number of good products out of 10 randomly chosen stocks.
Assuming that $n$ bolts have been manufactured, there are $0.96n$ bolts that can be used.

(2)  $P(X < 9) = 1 - P(X \ge 9)$

where,

$P(X \ge 9) = P(X=9) + P(X=10) = \binom{10}{1}\frac{0.96n}{n}\frac{0.96n-1}{n}\frac{0.96n-2}{n}...\frac{0.96n-8}{n}\frac{0.4n}{n} + \frac{0.96n}{n}\frac{0.96n-1}{n}\frac{0.96n-2}{n}...\frac{0.96n-8}{n}\frac{0.96n-9}{n}$